# How to install and use the latest version of selenium with Firefox on Ubuntu 22.04LTS?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox

I want to automate the login process to the pfsense captive portal, in order to do this I use Ubuntu 22.04LTS arm64. To be able to connect to this portal I have to enter my username, password, accept the cgu and then press accept. So to automate this I've seen that I can use selenium with Firefox, I've done the steps of the selenium website to install it for Python and for the geckodriver, after I wrote my code and want to run it, an error appear.

The code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

```
The error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/flo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 134, in run
    completed_proc = subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 503, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1863, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/flo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/flo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
  File "/home/flo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 103, in driver_location
    output = self.run(args)
  File "/home/flo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 140, in run
    raise WebDriverException(f"Unsuccessful command executed: {command}") from err
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unsuccessful command executed: /home/flo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager --browser firefox --output json


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/flo/Documents/script.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/flo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
  File "/home/flo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 41, in get_path
    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for firefox using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

Comment: You should use playwright instead. It is a much newer python library, and does NOT require a webdriver. Firefox is one of the default browsers that come with playwright, as well as chromium, webkit, and even branded browsers like chrome and msedge. Selenium, on the other hand, has crashing and webdriver problems, and should probably be avoided.